# LaTeX beamer which style is this?

Tags: beamer, themes

I have got a lecture and there were the following frames used in the presentation. Can anyone please tell me which style this is, because I really would like to use this as well.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like metropolis with different colours

Comment: I just checked it, I guess you are right. Thanks for the hint! :)

Comment: You're welcome! If you need help with changing the colour of some element, please feel free to ask!

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Indeed it isn´t that easy. The preamble I found online is very short, but the font ist printed in a dark gray color. Do you know how to change that to black?

Comment: Try `\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}`. If this does not work, I would need to see your code

Comment: Yes, it worked fine, thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme looks like the `moloch` theme with a couple of colour tweaks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{76,138,225}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=red,bg=lightgray!50}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=lightgray!25}
\setbeamercolor{progress bar in section page}{fg=myblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=orange}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]

\begin{document}
  
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
  
  \begin{definition}[test]
  content...
  \end{definition}
  
  \begin{itemize}
  \item test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\section{title}
  

    
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry for just writing thanks, but this is awesome and helped me a lot! I read that you are trying to help to keep beamer from crumbling. I seriously hope that beamer is not under a real threat, it is just awesome, even though I do not a lot about it currently.

For me as a math teacher in middle school LaTeX is just great. Unfortunately a lot of teacher do not use it. Thanks for people like you, LaTeX works great :)

Comment: @montarenbici You're welcome! Don't worry too much about beamer, I don't think it will vanish anytime soon :)